# Is it possible to recover commits to local branches from origin/master?

Tags: git, github

I suspect this is not possible, but feels worth a shot. I previously maintained a local repository consisting of a master branch and several feature branches. The master branch was tracked by a remote repository on GitHub, with regular use of `git push` to keep this all up to date.

Following a catastrophic local failure, and today's 'recovery' from GitHub onto a new machine, I realised that a not-inconsiderable amount of  incomplete development work on the feature branches appeared to be lost.

The question then - is it possible for any commits to the local repo outside of the local/master to be available in the GitHub repo and, if so, what commands would retrieve these?

Comment: At one point you say you pushed regularly, but at the end of your question I'm not that certain. *Did* you push? If yes you can now `fetch` them, of course. Your last sentence is quite confusing, maybe consider reformulating it. Because the answer to the question *in the title* is definitely "yes".

Comment: I pushed the master branch to GitHub regularly (and just before the catastrophe); but in the GitHub repo, there is only the master branch. I've now assumed that remote branches might have needed to have been created on GitHub to track my local feature branches, but I never did this, so I don't know what I'd be `fetch`ing?

Comment: Only what's pushed is on the remote. Remotes don't magically keep in sync with your local repository. What nature is your catastrophic failure? Did your hard disk die? That unpushed data is lost.

Comment: Unfortunately the catastrophe was a laptop theft, so in fact quite unrecoverable. Thankfully most of the feature branches had been recently merged into the local master, so not too much has been lost, but hopefully this information is valuable to people as I (foolishly) assumed I had everything backed up on GitHub; a lesson I won't forget in a hurry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you clarified your initial question with :

> in the GitHub repo, there is only the master branch. I've now assumed that remote branches might have needed to have been created on GitHub to track my local feature branches, but I never did this

Then, if the feature branches (I mean other than `master` that you said *was* pushed) have **never been pushed** to the remote, any commit they had which were also **unmerged** into `master`, yes, are unfortunately lost.

Your best hope is to have kept in `master` history at least parts of what you need, and rebuild from that what can be.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that if you still have your local clone where the branches were present, which I am not too sure, based on your:

> Following a catastrophic local failure, and today's 'recovery' from GitHub onto a new machine

you can use the `reflog` (which is a log of `HEAD`'s positions).
If your checked out these branches, is a recent past, you will see their commits here.

Comment: I must admit that in my answer I've assumed "catastrophic" as meaning something unrecoverable in anyway whatsoever.